# Contentful graphql one too many relationship

Tags: graphql, contentful

I am trying to achieve this: **getArticleBySlugWithFilteredTags('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3')** using 1 query ( 1 request ) and avoid clientside filtering ( grab many and filter out with javascript ).

I have content type **Article** that has an entry type as list: **Tag** ( another custom content type ).

So there is a **one too many relationship**: an Article can have multiple Tags.

Now getting back to this: getArticleBySlugWithFilteredTags('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3').

1. Attempt using custom content type: Tag

Query:

```
data: articleCollection(limit: 1, where: {
  slug: "article-unique-1",
}) {
  items {
    title
    tagsCollection(limit: 5) { // here it would be nice if I can use "where": {name: "tag1"}
      items {
        name
        value
        linkedFrom {
          relatedArticles: articleCollection(limit: 7) { // other related articles that has the same tag as parent Article
            items {
              slug
              title
              category
            }
          }
        }
       }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The only thing that is missing here is the that I need to filter out the tagsCollection ( based on some property: name or value ).

I see that I am limited to use "where" on tagsCollection.

2. Attempt using contentfulMetadata tags

Query

```
{
  data: articleCollection(where: 
    {
      slug: "article-unique-1",
      contentfulMetadata: {
        tags_exists: true,
        tags: {
          id_contains_some: ["tag1", "tag2"]
        }
      }
}) {
  items {
    contentfulMetadata {
      tags {
        id
        name
        linkedFrom { // I can't use this here
          relatedArticles: articleCollection(limit: 7) {
            items {
              slug
              title
              category
            }
          }
        }
      }
     }
     slug
     title
     publicationDate
   }
  }    
}
```

With this approach I am not able to use the **linkedFrom** in order to get also other related articles that have the same **contentfulMetadata tags**. What should I do in other to achieve this making 1 query and no clientside filtering with javascript ?

Comment: As you pointed out a `where` would be great and necessary. Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible in a single query.

Comment: @stefanjudis yep, feels like it ... I've created a contact support ticket, when I am gonna get any info I will reply to this thread

Comment: Good luck! Afaik this is a long-lasting request, and I wouldn't keep my hopes up.

Comment: @stefanjudis yep, the support replied, it's not possible, 2 queries must be used

Comment: Such a bummer. :/